# Plugin for aptana/eclipse that saves my opened files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I wonder if there is a plugin that is able to save the current state of my opened windows?

In my case I work at a large system, and attend several bugs in different locations, i submit a bug to test, but lots of times some adjusts must be made.. the point is I don't remember the files i changed after a few days, so It is desirable that i can save the current state of my windows.

That feature would do pretty much the same as the auto-save state as when Aptana is closed.

http://imm.io/aMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a version control system to store your changes, then you could see which files you changed in which folders very easily. As if you commit them, your commit messages will list the changed files, and you can diff them to see what you changed. Have a look at Subversion or Git.

This is more of a workaround than a solution, as I'm not aware of such a plugin.